# reshape nested numpy array with shape similar to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy array `sample` and `r`.

`sample` is nested array and `r` is flat array (1-D).

I want to reshape numpy array `r` similar to the shape of `sample` array.

```
import numpy as np
sample = np.array([[[[1,0,0,1],[0,0.8,0.7,1]],[[2,2,0,1],[0,0.8,0.7,1]]],[[[1,0,0],[0,0.8,0.7]],[[1,1,0],[0,0.25,0.45]]],[[[0,1],[0,4]]]])

r = np.array([2,0,0,2,0,0.81,0.71,11,2,2,0,1,0,0.8,0.7,1,1,0,0,0,0.8,0.7,1,1,0,0,0.25,0.45,0,10,0,40])
```

desired array:

```
r_reshaped = np.array([[[[2,0,0,2],[0,0.81,0.71,11]],[[2,2,0,1],[0,0.8,0.7,1]]],[[[1,0,0],[0,0.8,0.7]],[[1,1,0],[0,0.25,0.45]]],[[[0,10],[0,40]]]])
```

Comment: `sample.shape` is `(3,)`  `r.shape` is `(32,)`.  The total number of elements don't match, so `reshape` is no good.  But if you want to match the nesting of the lists, I think you'll just have to do some painful list construction.  This isn't a `numpy` problem!

Comment: `[np.shape(s) for s in sample]` produces `[(2, 2, 4), (2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2)]`.  The nested lists, if turned into arrays, have different 3d shapes.